# Can we pass email body in API payload for sending email in salesforce marketing cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, email-template, send-email, template

I am exploring Salesforce marketing cloud's email APIs but am unable to find any email send API that allows sending email body (HTML content) in the send API like Braze ([braze api](https://www.braze.com/docs/api/endpoints/messaging/send_messages/post_send_messages/#request-body)). Is there any salesforce marketing cloud API that allows to send email by passing email content in the payload?

Use case:
I have an email template in my code/project and I want to call marketing cloud API to send that email to a user by passing the template as a payload in the API call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no standard API that could be used to achieve this.

Here is an idea, but it's not been tested and **I don't recommend it** even if it works.

You can try to create a template in Marketing Cloud using the Paste HTML feature and past an AMPScript variable in there as a single line of code

```
%%emailHTMLVariable%%
```

Create an email using that template and a DE with a single column named 'emailHTMLVariable' with no limit. Pass your whole email's HTML code in the API payload (considering the limits) and see if the email renders correctly.

Again, I don't recommend this approach! You should create the template/email in Marketing Cloud (paste the HTML code directly or create it using MC capabilities) and pass only the necessary data in your API payload. If you want your email to be dynamic and that is why you are considering this full HTML approach, please note that there are a lot of ways to create a dynamic content email in Marketing Cloud.

You should leverage Marketing Cloud capabilities to meet your requirements instead of passing the entire HTML code in the API payload.

Answer (score -2):

YES you can!

To ensure proper functionality, utilize 'httpgetwrap|' for each link within the email body. Please note that this method exclusively applies to the first 100 links. Be mindful of the email body's payload limits. However, it's possible to contain the entire transactional email within it.

When creating a Data Extension (DE) for storing transactional data, leave the size field empty to accommodate the complete storage of the email content.

Comment: I am sorry but I don't understand how this helps in my scenario.

Comment: do you ask about transactional api email send? if yes then the answer helps.